# PostgreSQL: select from table returns more columns than in table definition

Tags: postgresql

I see more columns returned when I run `select * from mySchema.myTable` than what is returned by `describe myTable` or from the query below

```
select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_name = 'myTable'
and table_schema = 'mySchema'
```

How can I find where the additional columns are coming from? I also want to find the data types of the additional columns

These additional columns' data look like when the rows were inserted

Edit1: added schema to the queries, additional information

Comment: Are you certain that this be reproducible?  Because it seems to me that this should not even be happening.

Comment: Postgres has no "describe" command. Are you talking about `\d` in psql?

Comment: Maybe you have more than one table with that name in different schemas. Your `select * from information_schema.columns` will show columns for all those tables, while `select * from mytable` will only pick one (the first on the search path)

Comment: Updated my question above. I added table schema to the queries, I see no difference

Comment: To confirm: there is no `describe` in PostgreSQL. Perhaps you are using a different database system.

Comment: Might be you are getting the system column, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/ddl-system-columns.html

Comment: What is the result of `select * from information_schema.columns 
where table_name ILIKE( 'myTable')
and table_schema ILIKE ('mySchema')` ?